# How to add a pre-compile step to an ejected create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, compilation, create-react-app

In a standard ejected create-react-app, when you change a source code file, you'll see:

```
Compiling...
Compiled successfully!
```

What I want is a custom command executed before the compilation step each time a file (with a certain extension, ideally) is modified.
I've tried to use a [webpack-shell-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-shell-plugin):

```
plugins: [
    ...
    new WebpackShellPlugin({
        onBuildStart: ['echo "Starting"'],
    })
]
```

And now I get this:

```
node run start

> webapp@0.1.0 prestart /path/to/a/webapp
> node scripts/start.js

Starting type checking and linting service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
Watching: /path/to/a/webapp/src
Executing pre-build scripts
"Starting"
Starting the development server...

ts-loader: Using typescript@3.0.1 and /path/to/a/webapp/tsconfig.json
Compiled successfully!

You can now view webapp in the browser.

    Local:            http://localhost:3000/
    On Your Network:  http://192.168.2.159:3000/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

Compiling...
Compiled successfully!
Compiling...
Compiled successfully!
Compiling...
Compiled successfully!
```

As you can notice, it works only once, before the first compilation, and then it's never called again.

Is there another place I should hook my script into? Or another plug-in?

Comment: use onBuildExit instead.

Comment: @PlayMa256 well, now it does run the script each time I change something, but – as the name suggests – it happens after the compilation, so not exactly what I'd like to have =/ 
Do you have any idea why it happens? A bug in the plugin? My misunderstanding of the building process?

Comment: so, best way is to create a plugin on the beforeRun hook: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/Compiler.js#L58

Comment: thanks, didn't know about it, new to webpack, I'll look into that :)